# Efficient method to retrieve a single, specific digit from a text file in Java

Tags: java, regex, text-files

My apologies if this question has already been asked before; I tried searching and did not find anything close to this.

I have a text file that I have read into a `String` in my Java program. I need to search that text file for a particular phrase, which contains a digit, and extract that digit for saving into an `int` variable. Here is a sample excerpt from one such file:

```
≥                                                                              ≥
≥CREDIT CARD TERMS                                                             ≥
≥ORDER IS ON HOLD FOR PREPAYMENT OF ORDER TOTAL + FREIGHT BY CREDIT CARD.      ≥
≥ORDER TOTAL DOES NOT REFLECT FREIGHT COSTS & WILL BE CHARGED AFTER ORDER      ≥
≥SHIPS. ORDER WILL SHIP _5_ WORKING DAYS FROM RECEIPT OF ALL APPROVALS &       ≥
≥RECEIPT OF CREDIT CARD FORM.                                                  ≥
≥                                                                              ≥
```

This snippet generally appears far down in the text file, but on on specific line. I need to extract the number `5` from the phrase "`ORDER WILL SHIP _5_ WORKING DAYS`" from the file.

I can already imagine one way of doing it, which comprises of two consecutive searches with regular expressions. The first would search for the phrase, then the second would search for the number. However, this seems rather inefficient to me, having to create instances of the `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes in both processes.

I think there must be some--more efficient--way of performing this extraction without the need for two RegEx searches. Is there such a way? Or is the only way to do this with those two consecutive searches?

*AMENDMENT 03/30/2016:* I neglected to mention that there **might not** be underscores surrounding the number I need to extract. This might affect any answer that doesn't use RegExes.

Comment: Are there multiple numbers in your text file? Or can it be assumed the number you're looking for is the last one in the text file? And finally, do you create the text file(s) yourself?

Comment: You can use  `Matcher#find()` for a regexp with a `group` like `ORDER WILL SHIP _(<groupName>[0-9]+)_ WORKING DAYS`, then `m.group("groupName")` will return it

Comment: @RoelStrolenberg: Yes, there are many numbers in the file, so I have to look for only the one that is in that key phrase.

Comment: @Kuzeko: I'm replying to your answer, below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote some code to compare two different examples, how to archieve your goal and the time needed. **If you are able** to do it like Einar wrote (with increased first substring-param of course) it will be much faster than using Regex.

Example-Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // CREATE TEST-DATA
    StringBuilder testSequenceBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    testSequenceBuilder.append("                                                                              ");
    testSequenceBuilder.append("CREDIT CARD TERMS                                                             ");
    testSequenceBuilder.append("ORDER IS ON HOLD FOR PREPAYMENT OF ORDER TOTAL + FREIGHT BY CREDIT CARD.      ");
    testSequenceBuilder.append("ORDER TOTAL DOES NOT REFLECT FREIGHT COSTS & WILL BE CHARGED AFTER ORDER      ");
    testSequenceBuilder.append("SHIPS. ORDER WILL SHIP _52_ WORKING DAYS FROM RECEIPT OF ALL APPROVALS &      ");
    testSequenceBuilder.append("RECEIPT OF CREDIT CARD FORM.                                                  ");
    testSequenceBuilder.append("                                                                              ");

    // TEST
    String testSequence = testSequenceBuilder.toString();

    // REGEX
    performAndPrintNanos(() -> {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("ORDER WILL SHIP _(?<g>[0-9]+)_ WORKING DAYS",
                Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE); // Edited with Kuzeko's pretty example. If you want the pattern to be case-sensitive, just remove the second param of Pattern.compile
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(testSequence);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("OUTPUT-regex: " + matcher.group(1));
        }
    });

    // SUBSTRING
    performAndPrintNanos(() -> {
        String pre = "ORDER WILL SHIP _";
        String suf = "_ WORKING DAYS";
        System.out.println("OUTPUT-java: "
                + testSequence.substring(testSequence.indexOf(pre) + pre.length(), testSequence.indexOf(suf)));
    });
}

private static void performAndPrintNanos(Runnable runnable) {
    long startNanos = System.nanoTime();
    runnable.run();
    System.out.println(System.nanoTime() - startNanos);
}
```

Gives the following Output:

```
OUTPUT-regex: 52
1759364
OUTPUT-java: 52
44476
```

**Update (Comments):**

How to use substring if the presence of underscores is unknown:

```
String pre = "ORDER WILL SHIP ";
String suf = " WORKING DAYS";
String output = testSequence.substring(testSequence.indexOf(pre) + pre.length(), testSequence.indexOf(suf));
if(output.startsWith("_")&&output.endsWith("_")){
    output = output.substring(1, output.length()-1);
}
int num = Integer.parseInt(output);
```

How to use Integer.parseInt(...) for "5" and return 5

The conditional cutting is exactly the same as above, that's why I use an inline-if-block in this case. Just to show another example:

```
String input = "\"5\""; // "5" escaped
int num = (input.startsWith("\"") && input.endsWith("\""))
        ? Integer.parseInt(input.substring(1, input.length() - 1)) : Integer.parseInt(input);
System.out.println(num);
```

**Update #2 (Comments):**

Linebreaks possible:

```
    String pre = "ORDER WILL SHIP ";
    String suf = " WORKING DAYS";
    String output = testSequence.substring(testSequence.indexOf(pre) + pre.length(), testSequence.indexOf(suf));
    // remove linebreaks
    output = output.replaceAll("\n", "");
    // Remove "_" in front and after the digit.
    if (output.startsWith("_") && output.endsWith("_")) {
        // Before (example): output = "_5_"
        output = output.substring(1, output.length() - 1);
        // After (example): output = "5"
    }
    int num = Integer.parseInt(output);
```

**Update #3 (Buffered Reader - Example)**

For large files you should read line by line using for example a BufferedReader. I presume the phrase you want to detect will not take more than two rows. But if you use a reader you need to have one row in cache, as I said in my comment.

This is an example how to achieve that:

```
        String cache = null;
        while (bufferedReader.ready()) {
            String readLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
            if (readLine != null) {
                readLine = readLine.replaceAll("\n", "");
                // we concat the last read line and the actual read one
                String concatLine = (cache != null ? cache : "") + readLine;
                String pre = "ORDER WILL SHIP ";
                String suf = " WORKING DAYS";
                // We check, if the concat line contains both: pre and suf
                if (concatLine.contains(pre) && concatLine.contains(suf)) {
                    String output = concatLine.substring(concatLine.indexOf(pre) + pre.length(),
                            concatLine.indexOf(suf));
                    // no need to remove linebreaks, because we're reading line by line
                    // Remove "_" in front and after the digit.
                    if (output.startsWith("_") && output.endsWith("_")) {
                        // Before (example): output = "_5_"
                        output = output.substring(1, output.length() - 1);
                        // After (example): output = "5"
                    }
                    int num = Integer.parseInt(output);
                    // break here too if you only have one digit in that input file.
                }
                // cached line is now the one we just read
                cache = readLine;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        } // And don't forget to close the Reader afterwards ;-)
```

Comment: Very nice! Interesting to see how you're able to perform speed tests on both methods. I don't suppose you know of a way that the Substring method could be used if the presence of underscores is unknown? Or if `Integer.parseInt()` can handle an input like "_5_" and return 5?

Comment: I'm glad that I could help you. See my updated post for the answer to your additional questions

Comment: Oops. I forgot that markdown likes to turn underscores into emphasis (italics). I meant to ask if `.parseInt()` could recognize`"_5_"` and make it 5. I've already tried and it fails, so I definitely need to go with your "Presence of underscores is unknown" method. And I can take it from here if other weirdness shows up in the future, thanks. One final question for you @Manuel: Will the non-Regex method work in case the "key phrase" wraps onto two lines? Or will the line break cause a problem?

Comment: Integer.parseInt(String) cannot parse "_5_". You'll have to cut this String before, using methods from above. Hint: s.replaceAll("_","");  

If you want to use the non-regex method and linebreaks are possible, call s=s.replaceAll("\n","") (where s is for example output in one of the above examples) on the cut String before. I'll add an example, too. This will remove the linebreaks. Note: If you read line per line, you should also make sure, that you have always two lines in cache, using that method.

Comment: If your textfiles are usually a lot bigger than just the excerpt you mentioned above, you should take a look at what @plastique mentioned. I also added an example for this to my answer just now.

Answer (score 4):

Non-regex-way. Not sure if it is more efficient though:

```
static final String PREFIX = "ORDER WILL SHIP _";
String s = // file content
value = s.substring(s.indexOf(PREFIX) + PREFIX.length(), s.indexOf("_ WORKING DAYS"));
```

Should be possible to do with a single regex too

Comment: This will not work. You have to increase the first substring-param (+"ORDER WILL SHIP _".length), so that s is cut after _

Comment: That is an awesome way of doing it that I never thought of. One catch, however, that I neglected to mention in my original post: There *may* or *may not* be underscores surrounding the number I need. I'll amend my post to make that clear. Still, you definitely get credit for such a nice solution!

Answer (score 1):

For a single regexp you can do as follows

```
String text = "SHIPS. ORDER WILL SHIP _5_ WORKING DAYS FROM RECEIPT OF ALL APPROVALS";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("ORDER\\sWILL\\sSHIP\\s_?(\\d+)_?\\sWORKING\\sDAYS");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(0));
    }
```

Comment: I think this is probably the most elegant solution I've seen which can be slightly modified to take into account the fact that the underscores might not be in the key phrase sometimes. I'm guessing that there is no need to name the group explicitly, as `m.group(0)` should work if it's the first (and only) group in the RegEx? I guess both are equally performant. Same with replacing `[0-9]+` with `\\d+`.

Comment: I would also modify the RegEx a little to account for the fact that the "key phrase" might wrap to a second line. I'm not sure if a literal space in the RegEx would work for newlines, but I doubt it. So I'll probably use something like `"ORDER\\sWILL\\sSHIP\\s_?(\\d+)_?\\sWORKING\\sDAYS"` instead, which *should* account for newlines.

Comment: sure, that makes more sense, that is the most flexible regexp I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

First of all why are you reading whole file into a String? That is inefficient and you do not need it. Use the `BufferedReader`'s `readLine()` to read the file line by line. And process the current line only. You will not consume unnecessary amount of memory this way.

Also using regex for repeating text is an overkill. Simple `Strings`'s `indexOf()` methods with "ORDER WILL SHIP *" and "* WORKING DAYS" as parameters should be enough to recognize the right line and desired number position in the line.

Then extracting desired `int` value is easy just call the `Integer.parseInt(String s)` where `s` is substring of the current line between indexes returned by the `indexOf()` calls.

Comment: Those are some excellent points you bring up, @plastique. And I see you acknowledge that @Kuzeko's method is the more performant, using `String`'s own built-in methods instead of RegExes. To address your second concern, see my comment to @Manuel's answer. For the first…

Comment: There are at least two reasons that come to mind immediately for why the file is being read as a String instead of line-by-line: 1) This is only one of several "search and extract" operations I need to perform on the text file. 2) The "ORDER WILL SHIP XXX WORKING DAYS" may not be all on one line. I need to see if it wraps to the next line, which is why I'll likely use the RegEx `"ORDER\\sWILL\\sSHIP\\s_?(\\d+)_?\\sWORKING\\sDAYS"`, which should take that into account.

Comment: ad 1)Still you do not need to have whole file in one string, Just prepare all searches you need to do in advance. And then apply all of them at current line. 
ad 2) Is this line wrapping really done by ending the line by "\n" or is it done just in editor for viewing purposes?

Comment: Sorry for not replying sooner. Manuel has greatly illustrated how best to utilize your recommendation of `BufferedReader` for only going through the file line by line (well, two at a time, really) to extract all the pieces of information I need. One last question, though: Is doing it that way more efficient than using Apache Commons' `FileUtils.readLines()` or `FileUtils.readFileToString()`?